# Error in LoadRunner

Tags: performance, load-testing, loadrunner

Im doing performance testing for a system implemented in Java.Im using load runner 9.1 in windows server 2003 32 bit OS.An error occurs when running a script in load runner controller.Script is generated in Loadrunner script generator using Ajax protocol.Script replay is successful and no errors detected. Error message says "You do not have license to run this Vugen user type". Is this a license problem or any other kind of problem? Need a quick reply.Thnk u

Answer (score 0):

"You do not have license to run this Vugen user type".

There is no restriction upon which protocol you may develop a script with, but the controller is limited to type and number of users.    Call your VAR or HP System rep for a quote on the number of users you need.

Comment: But the problem is that its not working with even one user.I have tried one user, two users and five users.Same error is displayed for all of them.

Comment: There is no restriction in VUGEN. In Controller if you have no license for the user type then you will not be able to execute even a single virtual user. You will need to purchase a license for virtual users of this type if you wish to execute tests

Answer (score 0):

Check the License you have. If it's only for WEB (HTML/HTTP) users then redo the script in WEB (HTML/HTTP) script mode and your problem is solved.

You WILL need to do much more manual correlation etc. for the HTTP script, but on the other hand you do not have to buy a license...

In any case you need to spend credits either by buying the license or spending more time scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Try with **Other Protocol type** , Try using Multi type Protocol , Combination of "HTTP & Win socket", or already working with Multi Protocol change to Single type Protocol , and check choose option according to requirement.